# Mobile browser persistent footer (Non jquery)

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile, web

I'm looking for a non-jquery solution to add a persistent footer overlay to my mobile site. It is similar to a popup ad that is on top of content but anchored to the bottom of the page.

I've been using a javascript approach to this:

```
window.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    function() {
        //if scrolled and offsets are the same (iphone)
        if(_self.initOffsetY == window.pageYOffset)
        {
            document.getElementById(_self.id).style.bottom = _self.initWindowHeight - window.innerHeight+"px";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(_self.id).style.bottom = _self.initWindowHeight - window.innerHeight - window.pageYOffset+"px"; 
        }
    },
    false
);
```

where initPage Height is the initial page height and initOffsetY is the initial offset of the page. This takes care of the case with the browser menu bar.

But it doesn't really work too well on android. The positioning is off. Can someone explain why? Thanks

Comment: Something like this: http://jsweeneydev.net84.net/

Comment: You could save your jQuery file as somethingElse.js if it makes you feel a bit more like it is javascript rather than voodoo. I can see very little reason not to use it, given that it is almost certainly already cached on each target device. ALternatively, you could rewrite the whole library as collections of your own solutions to common problems one by one, and see if you can shave a couple of bytes from the final compressed size.

Comment: @BillyMoon The "cached on almost every device" isn't really true, but not real important anyway as JQuery's somewhat small. Probably the reason ftsk33 doesn't want to use it is because they don't want to rely on any third-party script to do something fairly trivial. There's nothing (seriously) wrong with JQuery in itself, but it can lead to "oh well, I'll make my user download 1MB library files and hope it works" programming practices (our work's 'mobile' site is guilty of this). Plus, it's good to know how one's site is actually working.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney Almost exactly like that but ideally I would like to put in the main container and have it scroll on top of the page like an ad.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use either of these standalone scrolling helpers:
http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/
or http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: It seems like these don't allow the floating div to scroll on of the page. It looks like the they just change the middle content of the page to be scrollable.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "floating div" to scoll on of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to have two separate elements, a main wrapper and a footer div perhaps, and enable scrolling in just the wrapper (`overflow:auto;`)? This would avoid most browser inconsistencies, or even cases where JS is turned off.

There's a drawback though. You will need to program a method for scrolling inner elements for some mobile devices. There are libraries for this (gasp!), but frankly it isn't too hard to program yourself (as I've done with my site).

Comment: unfortunately this approach will not work in iOS < 5 and Android < 4, where `overflow:scroll` doesn't trigger scrollability on the elements

Comment: @gryzzly thus the need to program the scrolling method.

Comment: sorry for not reading to the end. however, I'd strongly recommend using one of the libs as bouncing and kinetic scrolling take some time to get right, and these thingies were there for quite some time and gathered a lot of feedback

Comment: @gryzzly heh, I didn't even bother with the 'bouncing' property for my site; just made a fairly seamless way to scroll. I agree with you though; if you're strapped for time, or if iPhone-esque functionality is important, just use a little prewritten code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attached to this approach of floating an element to where you want it / approximating position:fixed, you're going to have a number of things to check, one being html code that you've got to make sure there aren't any margins or padding interfering with the above script.  The quick hack solution would be to just measure the heigh difference and calibrate your script according to that.  The number you get from the calibration might be helpful in determining the source of the problem.  There are probably some additional tricks to make this work smoothly, but I would go with a library thats being used already, and it looks like there are a number of them:  http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

btw - the iscroll4 library will fix the scrolling issue with overflow:auto on ios  < 5, android < 4